# How can I set the date of a Wordpress post in the past using API calls?

Tags: java, wordpress

I'm trying to make a Java program that publishes posts on Wordpress using API calls. I have the following method:

```
private String createPost(){
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();        
        s.append("?");
        s.append("&title=").append("Title%20of%20the%20post");
        s.append("&content=").append("lorem%20ipsum");        
        s.append("&categories=").append("6");       
        s.append("&status=").append("publish");
        return s.toString();
    }
```

It works fine, but since I'm doing this program to move posts from an old HTML site to a new Wordpress blog, I need to set the date too so they don't appear as 'new', but I don't know how to do it.
I've tried both &date and &post_date but they dont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by adding both date modified and date posted:

```
s.append("&date=").append(formattedDate);        
s.append("&modified=").append(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include `date` parameter with the value in this format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`